# How do you properly write onclick events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use an onclick event with an anchor tag that will change the innerHTML of another element on the page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so all the code I'm using is below. I hope you guys can point out my mistake and tell me what it was I misunderstood. The JavaScript file is included after the body, but you can see that on the JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Pv2_al1290/vx5pnvtp/). So, when I click Settings, I want the BookmarkList div to show it's own HTML code, and the same for Home. The BookmarkList div will be the center of attention for this site. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong for this.

**HTML:**

```
<body id="bodyBG">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box header">
Header
</div>
<div class="box content">
    <div class="box subcontent1">   
        <div class="sdfgsdfgsdfg"><input id="categoryName" placeholder="Category Name"></input></div>
        <div class="sdfgsdfg"><input id="urlLink" placeholder="Site Address"></input></div>
        <div class="sdfgsddfg"><input id="bookmarkName" placeholder="Bookmark Name"></input></div>
        <div><button>Save</button></div>
        <hr>
        <input placeholder="Search Bookmarks"></input>
        <button>Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box subcontent2">
        <a href="#" id="settingsNav" onclick="myFunction(this)">Settings</a>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" id="homeNav" onclick="myFunction(this)">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Back</a>
        <a href="#">Forwards</a>
    </div>
    <div id="bookmarkList" class="box subcontent3 bookmark-list">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/bookmark-action-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var settingsNav = document.getElementById('settingsNav');
var homeNav = document.getElementById('homeNav');

var changeThis = document.getElementById("bookmarkList");

function myFunction(this) {
if (this === settingsNav) {
    changeThis.innerHTML = "<h3>Bookmarks</h3><hr>";
}
else if (this === homeNav) {
    changeThis.innerHTML = "<h3>Bookmarks</h3><hr><p>Store all your bookmarks here!</p><ul><li>An secure storage means for your privacy needs!</li><li>24/7 Availability</li></ul>";
}
else (this != settingsNav | homeNav) {
    changeThis.innerHTML = "Nothing to see here!";
}
};

document.getElementById("settingsNav").addEventListener("click");
document.getElementById("homeNav").addEventListener("click");
```

**The Solution:**
I always add the solution that was appropriate for my problems, so future observers can see what issue I had and what the solution was. My issue was not adding the function to my eventlistener. You do not need to specify onclick events inside the HTML code if you specify event listeners with accompanying functions in your JavaScript code. But without the functions tied to the eventlisteners, nothing will happen. I understand that now.

```
var settingsNav = document.getElementById('settingsNav');
var homeNav = document.getElementById('homeNav');
var changeThis = document.getElementById("bookmarkList");

function myFunction(event) {
var el = this;
if (el === settingsNav) {
changeThis.innerHTML = "<h3>Bookmarks</h3><hr>";
} else if (el === homeNav) {
changeThis.innerHTML = "<h3>Bookmarks</h3><hr><p>Store all your bookmarks here!</p><ul><li>A secure storage means for your privacy needs!</li><li>24/7 Availability</li></ul>";
} else if (el != settingsNav || homeNav) {
changeThis.innerHTML = "Nothing to see here!";
}
};

document.getElementById("settingsNav").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
document.getElementById("homeNav").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: You have inline HTML `onclick` event, and you have an `EventListener` on JS that has no function bound to it, gotta pick one way or the other, preferably JS `EventListener`

Comment: You have to pass a function to `addEventListener`?!

Comment: @Bergi IF I was that knowledgeable about the language, I wouldn't be here asking for help...

Comment: @pv2.al1290 I just wonder what you expected an `addEventListener` method to do without a listener… What did you think the call does?

Comment: Those who strongly lack the knowhow of this language do not find it easy to learn. I looked up dozens of examples, but it was not until I saw the second answer to this that I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove attribute event handlers from HTML. Change `function (this)` to function (event)`. You did not add an event handler at`.addEventListener()`call, where you can pass`myFunction` as a reference to to function to call when event is dispatched.

OR in JavaScript should be `||` instead of `|` at second `else..if`

Note, `<input>` element is self-closing, `</input>` is invalid HTML.

```html
<body id="bodyBG">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box header">
Header
</div>
<div class="box content">
    <div class="box subcontent1">   
        <div class="sdfgsdfgsdfg"><input id="categoryName" placeholder="Category Name"></div>
        <div class="sdfgsdfg"><input id="urlLink" placeholder="Site Address"></div>
        <div class="sdfgsddfg"><input id="bookmarkName" placeholder="Bookmark Name"></div>
        <div><button>Save</button></div>
        <hr>
        <input placeholder="Search Bookmarks">
        <button>Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box subcontent2">
        <a href="#" id="settingsNav">Settings</a>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" id="homeNav">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Back</a>
        <a href="#">Forwards</a>
    </div>
    <div id="bookmarkList" class="box subcontent3 bookmark-list">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
<script>
var settingsNav = document.getElementById('settingsNav');
var homeNav = document.getElementById('homeNav');

var changeThis = document.getElementById("bookmarkList");

function myFunction(event) {
  var el = this;
  if (el === settingsNav) {
    changeThis.innerHTML = "<h3>Bookmarks</h3><hr>";
  } else if (el === homeNav) {
    changeThis.innerHTML = "<h3>Bookmarks</h3><hr><p>Store all your bookmarks here!</p><ul><li>An secure storage means for your privacy needs!</li><li>24/7 Availability</li></ul>";
  } else if (el != settingsNav || homeNav) {
    changeThis.innerHTML = "Nothing to see here!";
  }
};

document.getElementById("settingsNav").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
document.getElementById("homeNav").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in Chrome by fixing couple of syntax errors.

update `else` to `else if`

```
else if (clk != settingsNav | homeNav)
```

update `this` parameter to something else in myFunction

```
function myFunction(clk)
```

no need to add event since you called myFunction in `onclick`, so remove:

```
document.getElementById("settingsNav").addEventListener("click");
document.getElementById("homeNav").addEventListener("click");
```

Somehow it didn't work in jsfiddler.